# Oracle sql comparison when splitting table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have big table TRANSACTION table, i want to get key column for jan 2015 and another column which are not belong to jan 2015, so that i compare which column which is already existing in the table or not.

- select key column from transaction where period = jan 2015
- select key column from transaction where period != jan 2015

then compare the both column which are already existing or not.
How do i write a oracle sql for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is only matter of checking if transactions EXISTS in other periods then use this:

```
select t1.tdate, t1.key_column,
     case 
       when exists (
         select 1 from transactions t2
           where t2.key_column = t1.key_column
             and t2.tdate not between to_date('2015-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd') 
                                  and to_date('2015-01-31', 'yyyy-MM-dd') 
         )
      then 'transactions in other months exists'
      else 'transactions in other months not found'
    end notices
  from transactions t1
  where t1.tdate between to_date('2015-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd') 
                     and to_date('2015-01-31', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Test with sample data:

```
with transactions as (
  select to_date('2015-01-01') tdate, 17 key_column from dual
  union select to_date('2015-01-11') tdate, 123 key_column from dual
  union select to_date('2015-01-31') tdate, 90 key_column from dual
  union select to_date('2014-06-22') tdate, 17 key_column from dual
  union select to_date('2015-02-01') tdate, 19 key_column from dual
  union select to_date('2015-02-01') tdate, 90 key_column from dual
  )
select t1.tdate, t1.key_column,
     case 
       when exists (
         select 1 from transactions t2
           where t2.key_column = t1.key_column
             and t2.tdate not between to_date('2015-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd') 
                                  and to_date('2015-01-31', 'yyyy-MM-dd') 
         )
      then 'transactions in other months exists'
      else 'transactions in other months not found'
    end notices
  from transactions t1
  where t1.tdate between to_date('2015-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd') 
                     and to_date('2015-01-31', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

output:

```
tdate      key_column    notices
2015-01-01         17    transactions in other months exists
2015-01-11        123    transactions in other months not found
2015-01-31         90    transactions in other months exists
```

If you want to compare transactions in a more complicated way please attach some input, desired output and your attempts, if any.

Comment: The above sql helps me to find the duplicates. Thanks Ponder.